# no se ejecuta el codigo de mi else

Tags: java, mysql, condiciones, else

estoy desarrollando un sistema contable y para realizar uno de los estados financieros que me piden en mi materia tengo que comprobar si existe un registro en la base de dato, si existe actualizarlo con el nuevo saldo y si no existe tengo que insertarlo, lo que pasa es que cuando no se cumple la condición en lugar de ejecutar el código del else simplemente termina el if como si no estuvieran relacionados, el programa no crashea y la consola no marca ningún error simplemente parece que la tarea hubiera terminado y se queda esperando la siguiente, mi código es el siguiente

```
 public void guardarMayor(String nomc, String idC){
String sql="SELECT * FROM polizas WHERE cuenta LIKE '%"+nomc+"%'";
conexion cc= new conexion();
Connection cn= cc.conexion();
Statement st;
    try {
        st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
          if (!rs.wasNull()){
  String totald, totalh,td,th;
  totald=TD.getText();
  totalh=TH.getText();
  td="0";
  th="0";
  String consulta;
  consulta= "UPDATE mayor SET idcuenta='"+nomc+" ',parcialdebe='"+totald+" ',parcialhaber='"+totalh+" ',totaldebe='"+td+" ',totalhaber='"+th+" 'WHERE idcuenta ='"+nomc+"'";
 try {
        st= cn.createStatement();
        int res= st.executeUpdate(consulta);
        if(res>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"registro actualizado con exito");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
              System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");
        }else{
              System.out.println("ayuda");
              System.out.println("entro al else");
  String totald, totalh,tipoc;
  totald=TD.getText();
  totalh=TH.getText();
  tipoc="c";
  String consultax;
  consultax= "INSERT INTO mayor( idcuenta, parcialdebe, parcialhaber, totaldebe, totalhaber, tipocuenta) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
 try {
        PreparedStatement pst= cn.prepareStatement(consultax);
        pst.setString(1, nomc);
        pst.setString(2, totald);
        pst.setString(3, totalh);
        pst.setString(4, totald);
        pst.setString(5, totald);
        pst.setString(6, tipoc);
     
        
        
        int n=pst.executeUpdate();
        if(n>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cuenta guardado exitosamente");
            cargartablaMayor();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ncuenta guardado exitosamente");
    }
        
                }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que estás basándote en el resultado del método [`wasNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), que no es lo que buscas. El método `wasNull` te dice si la última lectura de columna que has realizado tenía un valor `Null`. La última lectura de columna es la que has hecho con alguno de los métodos `getInt()`, `getString`, etc).

Dado que tu no invocas ninguno, asumo que `wasNull` devolverá siempre `False`, tu código le aplica el operador de negación y por tanto siempre entra al `then` del `if`, y nunca al else.

Lo que tu quieres saber es si la consulta devolvió algún registro y en base a eso hacer el `update` o el `insert`.

Para averiguar esto, utiliza el método [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) del `ResultSet`. El método `next()` devuelve falso si no hay un siguiente registro que procesar. Si lo invocas justo después de realizar la consulta y esta tiene algún registro, devolverá `True` (por lo que debes hacer el `update`. Si no tiene registros, devolverá `False` y entras al `else` de tu código.

En resumen, lo que debes cambiar es la condición del `if`, por:

```
if (rs.next()) {
```

Dicho esto, quiero comentar sobre la importancia de la indentación del código. Un máquina interpretará el código aún si lo escribes todo en una sola línea, todo pegado al margen izquierdo o como sea.  La indentación es para nosotros los humanos. Ayuda a que otras personas puedan leer con mayor o menor dificultad tu código y, eventualmente, te ayuda a ti también a leer más fácilmente el código que tu mismo escribes, o con mayor dificultad.  Estuve a punto de pasar por alto tu respuesta porque la indentación es, francamente, muy mala.

Espero puedas apreciar la diferencia, este es el mismo código, con una indentación correcta (si, hay diferentes manera de indentarlo, pero al menos, se apega a un estándar):

```
public void guardarMayor(String nomc, String idC) {
    String sql="SELECT * FROM polizas WHERE cuenta LIKE '%"+nomc+"%'";
    conexion cc= new conexion();
    Connection cn= cc.conexion();
    Statement st;
    try {
        st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next()) {
            String totald, totalh,td,th;
            totald=TD.getText();
            totalh=TH.getText();
            td="0";
            th="0";
            String consulta;
            consulta= "UPDATE mayor SET idcuenta='"+nomc+" ',parcialdebe='"+totald+" ',parcialhaber='"+totalh+" ',totaldebe='"+td+" ',totalhaber='"+th+" 'WHERE idcuenta ='"+nomc+"'";
            try {
                st= cn.createStatement();
                int res= st.executeUpdate(consulta);
                if(res>0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"registro actualizado con exito");
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ayuda");
            System.out.println("entro al else");
            String totald, totalh,tipoc;
            totald=TD.getText();
            totalh=TH.getText();
            tipoc="c";
            String consultax;
            consultax= "INSERT INTO mayor( idcuenta, parcialdebe, parcialhaber, totaldebe, totalhaber, tipocuenta) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            try {
                PreparedStatement pst= cn.prepareStatement(consultax);
                pst.setString(1, nomc);
                pst.setString(2, totald);
                pst.setString(3, totalh);
                pst.setString(4, totald);
                pst.setString(5, totald);
                pst.setString(6, tipoc);
                int n=pst.executeUpdate();
                if(n>0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cuenta guardado exitosamente");
                    cargartablaMayor();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ncuenta guardado exitosamente");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo había probado con el result.next y tenía el mismo problema, por eso lo cambié por el wasnull lo que por lo que veo solo empeoró las cosas en verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si solo cambiaste `.next()` por `.wasNull()`, tu problema en realidad era el operador de negación `!` y que, dado que el registro no existía, siempre intentaba hacer un update y nunca hacía el insert (dado que siempre entraba al `then` y nunca al `else`, pero por una razón muy diferente). Un saludo.